# Stop aging in sims 2

Tags: the-sims-2

Besides the elixir of life, is there any option (or maybe a cheat) to stop my sims from aging?

I'm playing Open for Business and would like to make a lot of money (simoleons) before he is retired and he is aging too fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the information found [here](http://www.cheatcc.com/pc/sims2.html#.UJPnJcXAfQI), complete the following steps to disable aging for your sim.

- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to display the console window
- Enter "aging off"

Comment: If I remember correctly, you don't actually need to activate the testing cheats mode before using Aging on/off.